# How to find the client's monitor valid refresh rates with Unreal Blueprints?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, frame-rate, blueprints

I am making a settings menu. This includes a `combo box` where you can change the refresh rate setting.

How do I find out the maximum allowable refresh rate of the current user's monitor, using Blueprints?

Comment: Why would you want that information? If you are making a settings window, why not allow some standard values (maybe from 30FPS to 200FPS?) and let the user decide what's best for them?

Comment: @TomTsagk I don't want the user to be able to select a refresh rate that their monitor cannot handle - seems unprofessional where an easy solution exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon consultation with external sources, I came across this code for a C++ function library that exposes the functionality in DMGregory's answer to Blueprints:

https://nerivec.github.io/old-ue4-wiki/pages/get-available-screen-resolutions-in-blueprints.html

The post reads:

---

Get Available Screen Resolutions in Blueprints

Contents

1. Overview
2. Code

   2.1. Header File

   2.2. Cpp File

**Overview**

The following Blueprint Node is based on the function provided by Rama, see . The provided function has the limitation that you cannot use it in your own Blueprint Library. The reason is because the FScreenResolutionRHI Type is not a BlueprintType. As I required such a function for my options UMG widget I wrote it, tested it and decided to share it.

**Code**

The following code is meant to be included in your own Blueprint Library. If you do not know how to make a Blueprint Library I recommend you read

**Header File**

First you declare the new FScreenResolutionRHI type. As mentioned in the comments it is not an exact duplicate of FScreenResolutionRHI. The reason is that when I used uint32 I was not able to use break or make nodes. My guess is that the Blueprint's Integer Type is defined as int32 in c++ and thus is not compatible with uint32. If someone can confirm this feel free to do.

```c
/**
 * Screen Resolution
 * @remark Engine type is not meant for blueprints so we replicate the type.
 * @remark The Engine type uses uint32 but we need to use int32. Otherwise it won't be possible to break/make this type.
 */
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FScreenResolutionRHIBP
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = ScreenResolution)
    int32 Width;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = ScreenResolution)
    int32 Height;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = ScreenResolution)
    int32 RefreshRate;

    FScreenResolutionRHIBP()
    {
        Width = Height = RefreshRate = 0;
    }
};

/**
 * Retrieve a sorted list of all screen resolutions supported by the player's display adapter.
 *
 * @returns the array of all supported screen resolutions.
 */
UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category = Utility)
static TArray<struct FScreenResolutionRHIBP> GetDisplayAdapterScreenResolutions();
```

**Cpp File**

```c
#include "RHI.h"

...

TArray<FScreenResolutionRHIBP> YourBlueprintLibrary::GetDisplayAdapterScreenResolutions()
{
    TArray<FScreenResolutionRHIBP> ResolutionsToReturn;
    FScreenResolutionArray Resolutions;
    if (RHIGetAvailableResolutions(Resolutions, false))
    {
        // Preallocate just enough memory to store all elements
        ResolutionsToReturn.Reserve(Resolutions.Num());

        for (const FScreenResolutionRHI& EachResolution : Resolutions)
        {
            FScreenResolutionRHIBP resolution;
            resolution.Width = EachResolution.Width;
            resolution.Height = EachResolution.Height;
            resolution.RefreshRate = EachResolution.RefreshRate;

            ResolutionsToReturn.Add(resolution);
        }
    }

    return ResolutionsToReturn;
}
```

Enjoy!

-- ( ) 13:27, 18 January 2015 (UTC)

Comment: This answer is currently link-only. If that page ever moves or becomes unavailable, future users won't be able to get much from this answer. Can you edit your answer to include at least a rough overview of how to put this solution into practice, so even if the link rots it still points future users in a fruitful direction?

Comment: Yeah I'll get on that later

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, it looks like you can use the [FScreenResolutionRHI](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/RHI/FScreenResolutionRHI/index.html) data structures fetched by [RHIGetAvailablrResolutions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/RHI/RHIGetAvailableResolutions/index.html), each of which reports a refresh rate.

[There's a code sample on this wiki page](https://michaeljcole.github.io/wiki.unrealengine.com/Solus_C++_Tutorials/#Solus_Options_Menu:_Screen_Resolutions) that looks useful:

```
static FORCEINLINE void GetDisplayAdapterScreenResolutions(FScreenResolutionArray& Resolutions) { 
    if (RHIGetAvailableResolutions(Resolutions, false)) { 
        for (const FScreenResolutionRHI& EachResolution : Resolutions) { 
            UE_LOG(YourLog, Warning, TEXT("DefaultAdapter - %4d x %4d @ %d"), EachResolution.Width, EachResolution.Height, EachResolution.RefreshRate);
        } 
    } else { 
        UE_LOG(YourLog, Error, TEXT("Screen Resolutions could not be obtained")); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I definitely should have mentioned this before, but is there any way to access these structs in BPs

Comment: Agreed, that should be in the original question.  At minimum, you should be able to create a custom Blueprint node that accesses this info, but I can't advise on anything built-in.

Comment: https://nerivec.github.io/old-ue4-wiki/pages/get-available-screen-resolutions-in-blueprints.html

This seems to provide a basic C++ Function Library to expose the functionality to Blueprints - I'll put up an answer tomorrow, or you can incorporate it into yours, so there is one correct answer.

Comment: Great find! I recommend posting your own answer, since you're in a better position to test it or capture relevant blueprint screenshots. I don't have Unreal installed atm, so what I've written above is just based on the first page of search results.